# How can I display all the results of a row in a loop within a loop?

Tags: php, loops, pdo

What I have currently looks like this
[image: Example]

What I want is that with section name "asd" you can also select "Home" and any other option which might be in there, but for some reason it isn't working.

```
<table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 60%;">Section name</td>
            <td>Edit section</td>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>Order</td>
        </tr>
        <form method="post">
        <?php
            $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM section ORDER BY sorder');
            $cquery = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM category');

            if($query->rowCount()){
                while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                    echo'
                        <tr>
                            <td><strong>' . $fetch['secname'] . '</strong><br />' . $fetch['secdesc'] . '</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php?p=edit&id=' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Edit</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?p=del&id=' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></td>
                            <td><select name="' . $fetch['c_id'] . '" class="form-control" size="1">
                        ';
                        while($cfetch = $cquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                            echo'<option value="' . $cfetch['c_id'] . '" ' . (($cfetch['c_id'] == $fetch['c_id'])? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $cfetch['categoryname'] . '</option>';
                        }
                    echo'
                            </select></td>
                            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '" value="' . $fetch['sorder'] . '" style="width: 60px;" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    ';
                }
            }
            else{
                echo '<tr><td colspan="4">' . $noResultsDisplay . '</td></tr>';
            }
        ?>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="section" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
        </form>
    </table>
```

The SQL that goes with it:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS category(
    `c_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `categoryname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `corder` int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `c_id` (`c_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`categoryname`)
)Engine=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO category (`categoryname`, `corder`) VALUES ('Home', 1);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS section(
    `sc_id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `c_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `secname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    `secdesc` varchar(500),
    `secimage` varchar(500),
    `sorder` int(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `sc_id` (`sc_id`),
    UNIQUE KEY (`secname`)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

I am using PDO and $handler is my connection point.

I can see that I am on the right track, but for some reason the second loop is only looping once even though it should loop multiple times.

---

After sending the form, I want to set the category in the database, this is my current code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['section'])){
        $fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $category = $_POST['category'];

        foreach($_POST as $data => $value){
            if($data != 'section'){
                $sorder = (int)$value;

                if($sorder != $fetch['c_id']){
                    echo"UPDATE section SET sorder = :sorder, c_id = :cid WHERE sc_id = :id', [':sorder' => $sorder, ':id' => $data, ':cid' => $category]";
                    //echo perry('UPDATE section SET sorder = :sorder, c_id = :cid WHERE sc_id = :id', [':sorder' => $sorder, ':id' => $data, ':cid' => $category], null);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason I can't get the options of the select menu to get send to the database.

Answer (score 1):

No need to run this second loop nested (it always produces the same output). I would first get this output in a string:

```
while($cfetch = $cquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $option .= '<option value="' . $cfetch['c_id'] . '" ' . (($cfetch['c_id'] == $fetch['c_id'])? 'selected' : '') . '>' . $cfetch['categoryname'] . '</option>';
}
```

Then just echo it in the loop:

```
while($fetch = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    echo'
        <tr>
            <td><strong>' . $fetch['secname'] . '</strong><br />' . $fetch['secdesc'] . '</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php?p=edit&id=' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" href="index.php?p=del&id=' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '"><i class="fa fa-times fa-fw"></i> Delete</a></td>
            <td><select name="' . $fetch['c_id'] . '" class="form-control" size="1">
        ';
    echo $option;
    echo'
            </select></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="' . $fetch['sc_id'] . '" value="' . $fetch['sorder'] . '" style="width: 60px;" /></td>
        </tr>
    ';
}
```

Comment: I don't get the question. What does $_POST array have (print_r($_POST)) and what do you expect it to have??

Comment: Sorry, I posted a wrong piece of code. Where I echo the query, I want it to display the correct information, I got the whole database part working, this is just for debugging.